# how to use ffmpeg to merge WebM audio (Opus) and MP4 video (H.264) into one MP4 file

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to merge WebM file with Opus audio + MP4 file with H.264 video into a MP4 file:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.webm -i video.mp4 -c copy output.mp4
```

However, I get an error:

```
[mp4 @ 0x56105a6d0a40] opus in MP4 support is experimental, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Experimental feature
```

Complete log:

```
ffmpeg version n4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.0 (Arch Linux 9.3.0-1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-shared --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'audio.webm':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.01, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 106 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.54.100 libopus
      DURATION        : 00:00:10.008000000
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2796 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2793 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
[mp4 @ 0x56105a6d0a40] track 1: codec frame size is not set
[mp4 @ 0x56105a6d0a40] opus in MP4 support is experimental, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Experimental feature
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

---

Update 1

I tried this command:

ffmpeg -i audio.webm -i video.mp4 -c copy -strict experimental output.mp4

but got a new error:

> [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000225b1eb07c0] Format
>   mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 detected only with low score of 1,
>   misdetection possible! [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000225b1eb07c0]
>   moov atom not found inputVideo.mp4: Invalid data found when
>   processing input

---

Update 2

I found that my input video is corrupted which caused the error in Update 1.

So once I ran the command in Update 1, it did give me a bigger mp4 file, but the file is still no audio.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/277642/how-to-merge-audio-and-video-file-in-ffmpeg):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.webm -c:v copy video480p.mp4
```

also, if you would like to re-encode the audio

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.webm -c:v copy -c:a aac video480p.mp4
```

As a beginner, I have no idea about what does -c:v mean, so I found this document which tells all about it.
http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Stream-specifiers

Comment: works perfectly fine as of march 2022 in Fedora 34

Comment: (Leaving extra info related to macOS) This command worked, but QuickTime cannot recognize the video data and plays only the audio (this means no thumbnail preview also), but VLC is able to play it normally. Then, I reconverted it from mp4 to mp4 using the basic `ffmpeg -i video480p.mp4 video480p_2.mp4` and it worked. I am not sure why though. (behaves this way as of December 2022 on macOS 13.1)

Answer (score 10):

## Problem #1: Opus in MP4

Add `-strict -2` (or the alias `-strict experimental`) as mentioned in your log:

> `[mp4 @ 0x5630ee4eb000] opus in MP4 support is experimental, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.`

Example command:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.webm -i video.mp4 -c copy -strict experimental output.mp4
```

However, newer versions of `ffmpeg` no longer consider Opus in MP4 to be experimental, so if you upgrade you won't need to add `-strict`.

Latest release version as of this answer is 4.2.2. Use a version from the git master branch or wait for 4.3 to skip using `-strict`.

---

## Problem #2: Invalid data found when processing input

The input file is corrupt. Unfortunately there is nothing `ffmpeg` can do about this.

---

## Problem #3: No audio

This means that your player, browser, or device does not support Opus audio in MP4 container. You'll need to re-encode the audio to AAC:

```
ffmpeg -i audio.webm -i video.mp4 -c copy -c:a aac output.mp4
```

Comment: thanks Logan, I will give it a try tonight once I'm home. But I just installed the FFMpeg yesterday and as you can see from the log, its version is 4.2.2 which is the latest version on its website: https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html so will adding -strict be working?

Comment: hi @llogan, tried and got a new error. I have updated my post to include the new error.

Comment: btw, how did you convert my image into those words? did you use OCR?

Comment: @Franva 1) 4.2.2 is the latest release version and it requires `-strict` when muxing Opus into MP4. Experimental status was removed **after** 4.2.2 was released. Release versions don't get new features, so it will always require `-strict` for Opus in MP4. The git master branch is where the code is developed, so if you get a build from that, or wait for 4.3, then you won't need `-strict` to mux Opus audio into MP4 container. 2) Your new error was coincidental and not really a related problem. As you said the input was corrupt. 3) No OCR. Just ran it on my computer and copy/pasted.

Comment: @Franva I updated the answer to address each of your problems.

Comment: appreciated :) hahaha when I saw your converted my image to words, I thought you were using some very good quality OCR to do this.

Comment: btw, I don't know whether my browser support Opus or not, but I still managed to merge the audio(webm) into mp4 without re-encode the audio to AAC.

Comment: This didn't work for me when trying to concatenate two WEBM files. The resulting file (output.mp4) only contained the first video, not both.